# Dragging UIButton on UIView in Interface Builder not working

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, subview, iboutlet

I created a new Xib file, called `MainViewController.xib`.  I dragged a `View` onto the builder, then plopped a `UIButton` on top of the view.  Nothing happened, my button is on the view but not considered a subview.  There is no hierarchy tree on the left column under the `View` icon that tells me my button is a subview.

Why is that?  Every time I control+drag from the button to the view icon, the information for constraints pops up, instead of anything regarding an `IBOutlet` connection.

I'm using Xcode 7.1.2

I can control+drag to from my button to my `.h` file and create a property, but other than that, it's not recognized as a subview.  Any help at all will be appreciated, I'm losing my mind.

Comment: Please try to restart the Xcode, internally sometimes Xcode crashed....may be it will help you

Comment: I restarted Xcode and my laptop, nothing changed.  I'm looking at all these videos online (for version 7.2.1) and every drap+drop sequence from the object library does exactly what it's supposed to.

Comment: any other thoughts?  Uninstall/reinstall?

Comment: Let me search for this...I will reply you

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot...good luck.  I'll continue looking around too